# java.lang.RuntimeException: Got unknown argument class: int[] when passing a JS array to a java

Tags: react-native

I am taking a class on RN with Kotlin and got stuck on this assignment. When I try to pass an array of integers from JS to Kotlin, I get the error java.lang.RuntimeException: Got unknown argument class: int[].

Calculator.kt

```
@ReactMethod
fun getSum(values: IntArray, callback: Callback){
  var total = 0;
  // get total
  callback.invoke( null, total)
}
```

from JS i call it like this:

```
   KTFile.getSum([1,2,3],(err,ok)=>{

   });
```

it works if I am working with methods that take single integers:

```
 @ReactMethod
    fun getSquare(value: Int, callback: Callback){
      var sqr = 0;
      // get sqr
      callback.invoke( null, sqr)
    }


   KTFile.getSquare(1,(err,ok)=>{

   });
```

How do I pass JS array to kotlin/java?

Answer (score 0):

Starting with version 1.1.50 primitive array translation utilizes JavaScript TypedArray.

From https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/js-to-kotlin-interop.html

Maybe try this instead.

```
fun getSum(values: Array<Int>, callback: Callback){
      var total = 0;
      // get total
      callback.invoke( null, total)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Morgen DIAZ: I get a different error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Got unknown argument class: Integer[]